# Reading line from file doesn't return the correct string with fs.readFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, readfile

When reading a file line by line with below code. It seems to not read the string correctly?

Part of the String on each line in file is this:
**b53pd4574z8pe9x793go**

console.log(pathcreatefile) correctly shows:
**b53pd4574z8pe9x793go**

But is seems that: fs.promises.writeFile does this?:
**b53'd4574z8pe9x793go**

Console error is this:
**(node:1148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\myproject\instances\b53'd4574z8pe9x793go\folder\testA.txt**

My code is the below. I have added the 3 lines I read from the file in the code:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
var i;


//1|one/a|test1|C:/myproject/instances/b53pd4574z8pe9x793go/folder/testA.txt
//1|two/b|test2|C:/myproject/instances/b53pd4574z8pe9x793go/folder/testB.txt
//1|three/c|test3|C:/myproject/instances/b53pd4574z8pe9x793go/folder/testC.txt
var textarray = fs.readFileSync("C:/myproject/folder/testfile.txt").toString('utf-8').split("\n"); //Read the file


(async () => {
    var thePromises = []
    for (i = 0; i < textarray.length; i++) {

        //1|one/a|test1|C:/myproject/instances/b53pd4574z8pe9x793go/folder/testA.txt
        const line = textarray[i].split("|")
        if (line.length == 4) {

            const pathcreatefile = line[3] //C:/myproject/instances/b53pd4574z8pe9x793go/folder/testA.txt
            console.log(pathcreatefile)

            try {
                    let tickerProcessing = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
                    await fs.promises.writeFile(pathcreatefile, "hello")
                    resolve()
                })
                thePromises.push(tickerProcessing)

            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e)
            }
        }
    }

    // wait for all of them to execute or fail
    await Promise.all(thePromises)
    })()
```

Comment: Did you try to change the encoding option? Like `fs.promises.writeFile(pathcreatefile, "hello", "utf8")`?

Comment: That did not work. Is was neccessary to use: var endOfLine = require('os').EOL; as seen in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to wrap fs.promises.writeFile into an extra Promise, it returns Promise without any wrappers.

Also you should the constant from 'os' package for line separator to make it work across different operating systems.
The following code will work for you:

```
         'use strict';
var endOfLine = require('os').EOL;
const fs = require('fs');
var textarray = fs.readFileSync("./testfile.txt").toString('utf-8').split(endOfLine);
(async () => {
    await Promise.all(textarray.map((textElement) => {
        const line = textElement.split("|")
        if (line.length === 4) {
            const pathcreatefile = line[3] 
            console.log(pathcreatefile)
            return fs.promises.writeFile(pathcreatefile, "hello")
        }
    }));
})()
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation as to what was wrong, not just a snippet

Comment: Thank you so it was: var endOfLine = require('os').EOL; that made it work as I could see. Good to know that I can write the promise like that also.